# Get the url change in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

I have **two** different projects.

**Authentication Project:** has host as `http://localhost:4200`
Here i will have a login page where user will enter the details for sign in.

After successful login the user will be directed to another Project called `Application`.

**Application Project:** has host as `http://localhost:8000`

So if the user was logged in successful he will be here in dashboard like `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` page at this application project.

As of this scenario everything is ok.

**Suppose** if the user was entering into `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` directly then i need him to redirect to `http://localhost:4200` for sign in.

Because without sign in, user cannot go to this project `http://localhost:8000/dashboard` directly.
Auth guard related things were made and everything was working properly.

**The thing i am in need** is if user gives the url as `http://localhost:8000/users` (note url is **users**) directly then he will be coming to sign in page and after sign in i need to redirect to **same url** where he came from.

SO the scenario is user entering the url manually as `http://localhost:8000/users` but he is not logged in and so he was redirected to login then after successful login he was redirected to `http://localhost:8000/` but **i need to** redirect him to `http://localhost:8000/users` because that is the place where he came from.

How to get the url where he came from?

I am using angular 7 applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the origin url as GET parameter to the redirect from localhost:8000/users to localhost:4200. Something like localhost:4200?url=%2Fusers

On the login page you check if the parameter is set. If it is set you redirect to localhost:8000/users else you redirect to default localhost:8000/dashboard

This example shows how to redirect

```
let currentUrl;
// get current url, e.g. currentUrl = "/users"
// or currentUrl = window.location.pathname
window.location.href = "http://localhost:4200?url=" + encodeURIComponent(currentUrl);
```

Remember to use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the url.

You can read query parameters with

1. Angular

   ```
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
       const url = decodeURIComponent(params['url']);
       console.log(url);
   });
   ```
2. VanillaJs

   ```
   let urlParam = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&").map(function(el) {return el.split("=");}).find(function(el) {return el[0] === "url";})
   let url = urlParam ? decodeURIComponent(urlParam[1]) : "";
   ```
3. VanillaJs

   [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#Example)
4. VanillaJs

   [Url.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams#Example)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185574/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-sablik-get-the-url-change-in-angular).

Answer (score 1):

In Your Auth Guard you can save the previous URL; redirect the cx to the login page if the cx wasn't logedIn. once the user has logged in successfully check if there is any setRedirect URL in the service, if yes redirect to that page else redirect to the default page.

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): boolean {
    const url: string = state.url;
    if (this.loginService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.loginService.setRedirectUrl(url);
    this.loginService.redirectToLogin();
    return false;
}
```

loginService.ts

```
setRedirectUrl(url: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('state', url);
}
```

Once the user has logged In check if there is any state key in local Storage if yes redirect to that URL else redirect to the default page. Hope this helps

Comment: I have mentioned in question that there is no link with two projects.. Authentication and application are two different projects.. Just storing the logged in user details in cookies and making redirection with ```window.location.href```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a angular service for example redirect service and it has a boolean flag 
and redirect url
and when user enter an url 
in  ngOnInit method you set the flag to true and use router module to get the url 
and on login page check the flag and redirect after logging in

Answer (score 0):

This is what we do:

In the AuthGuard

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

if (this.isAuthorized) {
  return true;
}

// not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
console.log("navigating to login page with return url: "+ state.url);
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
return false;
  }
```

And then in the login we redirect them back to returnUrl

Comment: I have already said that authentication is different project so.. For redirection we will give as ```window.location.href = 'http://localhost:4200';``` (this url is for login) and no ```this.router.navigate```

Comment: In such scenario how to pass the return url in ```window.location.href``` ?/

Comment: Isn't it still the same process? 1) Check authorization  2) If notAuthorized this.location.href = (loginurl)?returnUrl=state.url 3) In Login application get Url from querystring and navigate using this.location.href = ....